# Check if a URL exists without CURL call

Tags: url, curl, redirect, http-status-codes

I want to check if a URL exists or not, and if it does, whether it is redirecting to a new URL (in which case I want to get this new URL as well)

By using curl call (through any language HTTP library), this is easily achievable and I'm able to do so. I wanted to know if there exists some utility which I can use so I don't have to make this network call everytime. Or is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: If you want to check whether a network location exists, you’ll have to make a network call each time. You could cache your results somehow though, for a certain time period otherwise you risk outdated information

Comment: Yeah, that's what I think too. Its hard to scale this...too many practical issues. I'm not really expecting a working answer to this question either.

Comment: Just hoping if someone can come up with a hack